# aws web service call to api gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to call the AWS API gateway resource /apikeys to get a list of my api keys.  This isn't a part of the sdk yet so I'm trying to do the web service call in Ruby and I'm getting a 400.  What I've read indicates I'm not setting up the headers and body correctly.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm using the aws4 gem for signing the headers and the faraday gem to make the GET call. Here's the code & output.

```
#! /home/sburke/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby

require 'aws4'
require 'pp'
require 'faraday'
require 'json'
require 'time'

# create a signer
signer = AWS4::Signer.new(
  access_key: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  secret_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  region: "us-east-1"
)

# build request
headers = {
  "Date" => Time.now.httpdate,
  "Content-Type" => "application/x-amz-json-1.0",
  "host" => "https://apigateway.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
}
body="{}"

# sign headers
uri = URI("https://apigateway.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/apikeys")
headers_signed = signer.sign("GET", uri, headers, body)
pp headers_signed

conn = Faraday.new(:url => "https://apigateway.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")

resp = conn.get do |req|
  req.url '/apikeys'
  req.headers = headers_signed
end

pp resp.status
```

Here's the output of the code.

```
sburke@sburke-laptop:~/sandbox/aws_rest_ruby$ ./test.rb 
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
{"Date"=>"Sun, 11 Oct 2015 02:14:13 GMT",
 "Content-Type"=>"application/x-amz-json-1.0",
 "host"=>"https://apigateway.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
 "Authorization"=>
  "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAI2P7SWBU6FBHPMOA/20151011/us-east-1/apigateway/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;date;host, Signature=85536b2084c11492d7b1af612b4f0a83752bb921e8534155dfbebeaefde6a73d"}
400
```

Here's the output of the headers and the body is empty.  I don't get any more info from the faraday response object aside from the 400 and headers.

```
pp resp.headers
pp resp.body
{"transfer-encoding"=>"chunked",
 "date"=>"Wed, 14 Oct 2015 17:27:25 GMT",
 "connection"=>"close"}
""
```

Comment: don't think the URI should have the method in it (https://apigateway.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/apikeys) I thinks that should be included as an action in the query string and go into signing.

Comment: also, can you include the response you get along with the 400?

Comment: you've exposed your access keys in your output `"Credential ="`, and as this could be a security risk make sure you change them.

Comment: @hamitron the access key id is not sensitive data, only the secret is.  Rotating the keys now might be desirable but there is likely no substantial risk from exposing the key without the secret. Computationally infeasible to reverse-engineer, and all that.

Comment: I changed the uri to only be apigateway.us-east-1.amazonaws.com  No change. Still the 400 status.